# Unexpected error in Central Admin Site

Tags: 2013, error, central-administration

Sometimes my Central Administration site throws an unexpected error while accessing it for the first time of the day. Later on refreshing the browser, the central admin home page lands correctly and everything works fine as expected. I have encountered this issue few times. On investigating ULS logs I found below exceptions reported. I am running a 16 GB RAM on my WFE/App server and Distributed Cache service is running.

```
Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out.

Application error when access /default.aspx, Error=Request timed out.

Safe mode did not start successfully. System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.    
 at System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, Int32 sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, Int32 destinationIndex, Int32 length, Boolean reliable)    
 at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SafeAssemblyInfo.EnumAssemblyTypes(EnumSafeTypeCallback addSafeTypeCallback, Boolean logExceptions)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SafeControlsList.InitSafeControlsInfoFromConfig(Boolean inNonVRootAppDomain, SafeControlsContainer safeControlsContainer, SPWebApplication app, SPUrlZone zone)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SafeControlsList..ctor(SPWebApplication app, SPUrlZone zone)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SafeControls..ctor(SPWebApplication app, SPUrlZone zone)

Unexpected Exception in SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper::InitializeDataCacheFactory for usage 'DistributedViewStateCache' - Exception 'Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheException: ErrorCode<ERRCA0018>:SubStatus<ES0001>:The request timed out.. Additional Information : The client was trying to communicate with the server : net.tcp://TDCLPPMWEBAPP01:22233    
 at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.ThrowException(ResponseBody respBody, RequestBody reqBody)    
 at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory.GetCacheProperties(RequestBody request, IClientChannel channel)    
 at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory.GetCache(String cacheName)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper.InitializeDataCacheFactory()'.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the server is not warmed up first time.

> SharePoint app pools recycle every night, or they get cranky. But
>   because they recycle every night the first person to hit SharePoint
>   each morning has to wait for the app pools to warm back up, which
>   makes them cranky

Reference - [Using PowerShell to warm up SharePoint 2013](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=404)

Download the below powershell script and you can schedule it to run as per your schedule. This will warm up the web applications and the service applications so you wont face this time out issue.

[SPbestwarmup](https://github.com/spjeff/spbestwarmup)

Comment: My thoughts too +1

Comment: Thanks Gautam. Can we schedule app pools from IIS Manager? Is it a good thing that SharePoint app pools are recycling every night?

Comment: 1) You can schedule the PS script using Windows Scheduler,
 not IIS manager. You can set/modify schedule  as per this link - (http://get-spscripts.com/2011/01/running-sharepoint-powershell-script.html)
2) Yes its good thing, usually happens early morning(server time). it clears up the memory for the site . Its configurable as well (https://www.habaneroconsulting.com/insights/Set-the-Specific-Times-to-Recycle-an-Application-Pool-with-PowerShell)